# Overriding the [] for constructing Python lists

Tags: python, list, overriding

I would like to replace lists in a program with another class in order to obtain more information on the underlying data. It's easy enough to do the following replacement:

```
list = ObservableList  # new class, compatible with list
```

so that `list([1, 2, 3])` returns an `ObservableList`, but this does not affect expressions like `[1, 2, 3]` or list comprehensions, which will still return a Python list. Is there any way to override these constructions so that they return an `ObservableList` as well?

Comment: Ummm.. you can use some lib to handle stuff at byte-code level and modify [`BUILD_LIST`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_LIST) step somehow. But won't be worth it. It's better to be more explicit and check the type and change it to `ObservableList` wherever required.